# invalid content-type returning 404 rather than 406 in spring mvc RESTful controller

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I'm creating a RESTful controller using Spring 3.0.5.  I've specified the content type that I'm willing to accept but find that if a request is sent with something else, I get a 404 rather than the expected 406.  Can someone please point out what I'm missing?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> sayHello(@PathVariable("name") String username) {
    Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<String,String>();
    result.put("greeting", "Hello "+username);
    return result;
}
}
```

If I send a request with header of "accept=application/json", everything works fine. However a request with header of "accept="text/xml", returns a 404.

Thanks!

--john

Comment: Let's see where (which URL) you are making the request and with what headers. Also does your controller have its own `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: The URL is like: http://localhost:8080/aurora/hello/jcc with a header of accept=text/xml.  The controller does have it's own RequestMapping, e.g. `@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorldController {...}`

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe this might have been an issue/bug in 3.0 versions that was fixed/changed in 3.1+. Can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, that seems to be it.  I upgraded to Spring 3.2.6 and now see the behavior I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my comment as an answer for completeness.

I would suggest you upgrade to a version 3.1 and higher. These handler processing issues seem to have been fixed.

Related issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10085